# ChakraUI & Typescript custom theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to ChakraUI and Typescript mixed together.
Following ChakraUI DOC I have created a file like this:

```
import { theme } from '@chakra-ui/core';

const customTheme = {
  ...theme,
  colors: {
    ...theme.colors,
    brand: {
      900: '#1a365d',
      800: '#153e75',
      700: '#2a69ac',
    },
  },
};

export default customTheme;
```

Unfortunately on `customTheme` I have a rid of these errors:

```
Exported variable 'customTheme' has or is using name 'ZIndices' from external module "/Users/username/project-test/node_modules/@chakra-ui/core/dist/theme/index" but cannot be named.ts(4023)
Exported variable 'customTheme' has or is using name 'Radii' from external module "/Users/username/project-test/node_modules/@chakra-ui/core/dist/theme/index" but cannot be named.ts(4023)
Exported variable 'customTheme' has or is using name 'Opacity' from external module "/Users/username/project-test/node_modules/@chakra-ui/core/dist/theme/index" but cannot be named.ts(4023)
Exported variable 'customTheme' has or is using name 'Borders' from external module "/Users/username/project-test/node_modules/@chakra-ui/core/dist/theme/index" but cannot be named.ts(4023)
```

Any hint?
Using:
TS: latest version
ChakraUI: latest version

Thank you in advance

Comment: What line is giving you those errors? How are you importing/using the `customTheme` variable?

Comment: @AlexWayne `const customTheme` in the code above

Answer (score 0):

this code should work for you:

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const customTheme = {
  ...theme,
  colors: {
    ...theme.colors,
    brand: {
      900: '#1a365d',
      800: '#153e75',
      700: '#2a69ac',
    },
  },
};

export default extendTheme(customTheme);
```

and then you can import this in `_App.js`  and add it in ChakraProvider like this:

```
<ChakraProvider theme={customTheme}>
```